# Maximum number of significance tests

Tags: correlation, multiple-comparisons

I have a data set comprising of responses from approximately 385 people on several variables such as their shopping habits, mode of transport to the shopping centre  etc. I want to do Pearson correlation on the variables (by age, gender, income level etc. of the respondents).

**Is there any rule that says what would be the maximum number of tests that can be reliably performed on this data set?** I am unsure if "reliable" is the correct term; I mean "valid" or "sound" in this case.

My alpha is 0.05 and I have corrected it using Sidak's method, so the experiment wise error is 0.05 for the 80 tests that I want to perform on this data set.

Comment: It looks like there is an error in the reported $\alpha$ value. Setting your FWER at 5% means that nominal $\alpha$'s are about 0.000641.

Comment: I wonder whether looking at correlation coefficients would be useful.  What would the test results tell you?

Comment: Your question is closely related to this one: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5750/look-and-you-shall-find-a-correlation

Comment: @chi It is 0.05 for all 80 tests which means, as you correctly pointed out, that the alpha is lower for the individual tests.