# Stepwise meta-regression with R (metafor)

Tags: r, meta-analysis, stepwise-regression, multivariate-analysis, meta-regression

I am using the "metafor" package to do a multivariate meta-regression in "R".

I have 6 predictors and I am able to run the full model (all the predictors simultaneously in the model) just fine.

However, I would like to do a backward deletion meta-regression. I cannot figure out how to do it, and I am wondering if this is a possibility.

Thank you.

Comment: Why would you want to do such a thing? Are you trying to demonstrate why it is a bad idea?

Comment: Not really, but I would be happy if you could explain briefly why it is a bad idea. To me and to some others with already published papers using this technique.

Comment: If you use stepwise regression: 1) Your parameter estimates will be biased away from 0 2) Your standard errors will be too small 3) Your p-values will be too small. See e.g. (this thread)[http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69452/how-does-stepwise-regression-work] for more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an extensive account of how to do model selection using the metafor and  glmulti packages on the metafor project home pages [here](http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:model_selection_with_glmulti). Note that this does not use step-wise selection which has been widely criticised but fits all possible models from a specified set (all main effects, all two-way interactions and main effects, and so on). The main criterion used in the example is AICc but others are available. One advantage of this approach over step-wise is that it encourages examination of all (or a subset) of the models rather than having a focus just on the "best" one which usually reveals that there are a number of models virtually indistinguishable from the "best" one.