# Choosing variables in multiple linear regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, variable

I am trying to make multiple linear regression models for multiple crops where my dependent variable is Yield of crops for ex. Yield of Wheat, Rice, etc. I have data set in which each row represent a district and for each district there are multiple variable such as climatic variables such as soil type, rainfall, topography etc and aggricultural input variables such as fertilizers, labors etc, and also there are distinct columns for yield of each crop.
i am thinking of including fertilizer cost in RS/hectare which is for whole district, not specific to any one crop, so i am not sure about it, can i include this variable in my multiple regression model for single crop model.
link for the data -> https://github.com/Vikram1511/Econometrics_project/blob/master/~%24Excel1.xlsx

EDIT

this is not duplicate of the any thread on stack exchange, my question is not about which variable are significant or not significant and on which basis choose them, i have not even run the model, right now i am trying to formulate the structure of model and therefor choosing which variable i can choose? please read the above paragrpah of question carefully

THIS IS NOT DUPLICATE ANY OF THEM, PLEASE GUYS DON'T JUST TAG THIS WITHOUT EVEN READING THE QUESTION STATEMENT! THIS IS VERY DISAPPOINTING!

Comment: There are some good answers here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21265/choosing-variables-to-include-in-a-multiple-linear-regression-model

Comment: @william3031 did you even read the question? or just read the title and tagged as duplicate?please read it and tell me how it is similar to that thread

Comment: Maybe you should show some data so it makes more sense.

Comment: https://github.com/Vikram1511/Econometrics_project/blob/master/~%24Excel1.xlsx

Comment: @william3031 i added a link for the data