# Correlation between first and third variable, given correlations with second

Tags: correlation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If A and B are correlated with C, why are A and B not necessarily correlated?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5747/if-a-and-b-are-correlated-with-c-why-are-a-and-b-not-necessarily-correlated)

Lets say, we have correlation between $x$, $y$ as $corr(x,y)$ and correlation between $y$, $z$ as $corr(y,z)$. What can be said of the correlation between $x$ and $z$ i.e. $corr(x,z)$?