# Bound for the correlation of three random variables

Tags: correlation, correlation-matrix

There are three random variables, $x,y,z$. The three correlations between the three variables are the same. That is,

$$\rho=\textrm{cor}(x,y)=\textrm{cor}(x,z)=\textrm{cor}(y,z)$$

What is the tightest bound you can give for $\rho$?

Comment: Presumably by "pho", you mean *rho* ($\rho$). However, your question is not clear. What do you mean by "What’s the tightest bound you can give"?

Comment: Well the name of the variable is just a dummy. By tightest bound, I mean something like [-1, 1] for a correlation, but this clearly isn't the tightest possible bound.

Comment: Do you mean that rho=cor(x,y)=cor(x,z)=cor(y,z), and what are the limits for rho?

Comment: Yes I mean that rho=cor(x,y)=cor(x,z)=cor(y,z) and what are the limits for rho. Dilip, can you extend that to say that rho must be non-negative, ie >= 0?

Comment: **Closely related**: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5747.  It's not quite a duplicate, but its answers provide some results for the general trivariate correlation matrix that are easy to specialize to this case. The two points they do not cover are sufficiency--namely, showing that any matrix whose coefficients satisfy the conditions actually is a correlation matrix for some distribution--and tightness (there are no better bounds).

Comment: See also the duplicate question here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/97912/which-equal-correlations-of-three-random-variables-are-possible with an answer that is easier to parse for those with less of a background in mathematics.

Comment: For the result pointed out above: "the minimum common correlation of n random variables is −1/(n−1)", could anybody point me to a reference that would be appropriate to cite in an academic journal? I'd like to have a citation for this point, and it's off-topic enough to make reproducing the proof inappropriate. It would also, unfortunately, not be considered acceptable to cite stackexchange. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @James This is so well known I'm sure you will find it in just about any textbook that discusses multiple correlation.  I believe I first encountered it in Lee Wilkinson's Systat manual... .

Comment: A textbook to cite for this is Seber & Lee "Linear Regression Analysis" (At least it was in first edition ...)

Answer (score 50):

The common correlation $\rho$ can have value $+1$ but not $-1$. If $\rho_{X,Y}= \rho_{X,Z}=-1$, then $\rho_{Y,Z}$ cannot equal $-1$ but is in fact $+1$.
The smallest value of the common correlation of three random variables
is $-\frac{1}{2}$. More generally,
the minimum common correlation of $n$ random variables is $-\frac{1}{n-1}$
when, regarded as vectors, they are at the vertices of a simplex (of dimension $n-1$)
in $n$-dimensional space.

Consider the variance of the sum of
$n$ unit variance random variables $X_i$.  We have that
$$\begin{align*}
\operatorname{var}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right)
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname{var}(X_i) + \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j\neq i}^n \operatorname{cov}(X_i,X_j)\\
&= n + \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j\neq i}^n \rho_{X_i,X_j}\\
&= n + n(n-1)\bar{\rho} \tag{1}
\end{align*}$$
where $\bar{\rho}$ is the *average value* of the $\binom{n}{2}$correlation coefficients.
But since $\operatorname{var}\left(\sum_i X_i\right) \geq 0$, 
we readily get from
$(1)$ that 
$$\bar{\rho} \geq -\frac{1}{n-1}.$$

So, the average value of a correlation coefficient is
*at least* $-\frac{1}{n-1}$. If *all* the correlation coefficients
have the *same* value $\rho$, then their average also
equals $\rho$ and so we have that 
$$\rho \geq -\frac{1}{n-1}.$$
Is it possible to have random variables for which the common
correlation value $\rho$  *equals*
$-\frac{1}{n-1}$? Yes.  Suppose that the $X_i$ are *uncorrelated* 
unit-variance random variables  and set
$Y_i = X_i - \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n  X_j = X_i -\bar{X}$. Then, $E[Y_i]=0$, while
$$\displaystyle \operatorname{var}(Y_i) 
= \left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^2 + (n-1)\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^2
= \frac{n-1}{n}$$ 
and
$$\operatorname{cov}(Y_i,Y_j) = -2\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) +
(n-2)\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^2 = -\frac{1}{n}$$
giving 
$$\rho_{Y_i,Y_j} 
= \frac{\operatorname{cov}(Y_i,Y_j)}{\sqrt{\operatorname{var}(Y_i)\operatorname{var}(Y_j)}}
=\frac{-1/n}{(n-1)/n} 
= -\frac{1}{n-1}.$$
Thus the $Y_i$ are random variables achieving the minimum common
correlation value of $-\frac{1}{n-1}$. Note, incidentally, that
$\sum_i Y_i = 0$, and so, regarded as vectors, the random variables
lie in a $(n-1)$-dimensional hyperplane of $n$-dimensional space.

Comment: I'm a little confused by this answer. I think it correctly shows that the p >= -1/(n-1) bound is necessary and sufficient for the variance of a sum of variables to be non-negative, but it doesn't seem to actually be necessary and sufficient for positive-definiteness of the correlation matrix in general.

Comment: @user49404 Correlation matrices don't need to be positive _definite_; only positive _semidefiniite_ (also called nonnegative definite by some people). Also, the OP's question only asked for a bound on the minimum value of the _common_ correlation of the (three) variables and not about correlation matrices in general. Be that as it may, see [this answer of mine](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/69117/6633) for the general result.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a 2 in front of the next sum? And really there are n choose 2 or (n-1)n/2 pairs, so you result to $n(n-1)\rho$, not $n(n-1)\bar{\rho}$

Comment: @user2330624 The sum of $n(n-1)$ _possibly different_ $\rho_{I,j}$'s equals $n(n-1)\bar{\rho}$ where $\bar{\rho}$ is the average value of the correlation coefficients.  That $\rho_{I,j}= \rho_{j,i}$ does not change this fact. That  all the $\rho_{I,j}$'s have the same value does not change this fact. Thus, even when all the $\rho_{I,j}$'s have the same value $\rho$, this common value of the $\rho_{I,j}$'s is bounded below by $-\frac{1}{n-1}$.  There are no $2$'s required anywhere.

Answer (score 39):

**The tightest possible bound is $-1/2 \le \rho \le 1$.**  All such values can actually appear--none are impossible.

To show there is nothing especially deep or mysterious about the result, this answer first presents a completely elementary solution, requiring only the obvious fact that variances--being the expected values of squares--must be non-negative.  This is followed by a general solution (which uses slightly more sophisticated algebraic facts).

### Elementary solution

**The variance of any linear combination of $x,y,z$ must be non-negative.**  Let the variances of these variables be $\sigma^2, \tau^2,$ and $\upsilon^2$, respectively.  All are nonzero (for otherwise some of the correlations would not be defined).  Using the basic properties of variances we may compute

$$0 \le \text{Var}(\alpha x/\sigma + \beta y/\tau + \gamma z/\upsilon) = \alpha^2 +\beta^2+\gamma^2 + 2\rho(\alpha\beta+\beta\gamma+\gamma\alpha)$$

for all real numbers $(\alpha, \beta, \gamma)$.

Assuming $\alpha+\beta+\gamma\ne 0$, a little algebraic manipulation implies this is equivalent to

$$\frac{-\rho}{1-\rho} \le \frac{1}{3} \left(\frac{\sqrt{(\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2)/3}}{(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)/3}\right)^2.$$

The squared term on the right hand side is the ratio of two power means of $(\alpha, \beta, \gamma)$.  The [elementary power-mean inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean#Inequality_between_any_two_power_means) (with weights $(1/3, 1/3, 1/3)$) asserts that ratio cannot exceed $1$ (and will equal $1$ when $\alpha=\beta=\gamma\ne 0$).  A little more algebra then implies

$$\rho \ge -1/2.$$

The explicit example of $n=3$ below (involving trivariate Normal variables $(x,y,z)$) shows that all such values, $-1/2 \le \rho \le 1$, actually do arise as correlations.  This example uses only the definition of multivariate Normals, but otherwise invokes no results of Calculus or Linear Algebra.

### General solution

#### Overview

Any correlation matrix is the covariance matrix of the standardized random variables, whence--like all correlation matrices--it must be positive semi-definite.  Equivalently, its eigenvalues are non-negative.  This imposes a simple condition on $\rho$: it must not be any less than $-1/2$ (and of course cannot exceed $1$).  Conversely, any such $\rho$ actually corresponds to the correlation matrix of some trivariate distribution, proving these bounds are the tightest possible.

---

#### Derivation of the conditions on $\rho$

Consider the $n$ by $n$ correlation matrix with all off-diagonal values equal to $\rho.$ (The question concerns the case $n=3,$ but this generalization is no more difficult to analyze.)  Let's call it $\mathbb{C}(\rho, n).$  By definition, $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of provided there exists a nonzero vector $\mathbf{x}_\lambda$ such that

$$\mathbb{C}(\rho,n) \mathbf{x}_\lambda = \lambda \mathbf{x}_\lambda.$$

These eigenvalues are easy to find in the present case, because

1. Letting $\mathbf{1} = (1, 1, \ldots, 1)'$, compute that

   $$\mathbb{C}(\rho,n)\mathbf{1} = (1+(n-1)\rho)\mathbf{1}.$$
2. Letting $\mathbf{y}_j = (-1, 0, \ldots, 0, 1, 0, \ldots, 0)$ with a $1$ only in the $j^\text{th}$ place (for $j = 2, 3, \ldots, n$), compute that

   $$\mathbb{C}(\rho,n)\mathbf{y}_j = (1-\rho)\mathbf{y}_j.$$

Because the $n$ eigenvectors found so far span the full $n$ dimensional space (proof: an easy row reduction shows the absolute value of their determinant equals $n$, which is nonzero), they constitute a basis of *all* the eigenvectors.  We have therefore found all the eigenvalues and determined they are either $1+(n-1)\rho$ or $1-\rho$ (the latter with multiplicity $n-1$).  In addition to the well-known inequality $-1 \le \rho \le 1$ satisfied by all correlations, non-negativity of the first eigenvalue further implies

$$\rho \ge -\frac{1}{n-1}$$

while the non-negativity of the second eigenvalue imposes no new conditions.

---

#### Proof of sufficiency of the conditions

The implications work in both directions: provided $-1/(n-1)\le \rho \le 1,$ the matrix $\mathbb{C}(\rho, n)$ is nonnegative-definite and therefore is a valid correlation matrix.  It is, for instance, the correlation matrix for a multinormal distribution.  Specifically, write

$$\Sigma(\rho, n) = (1 + (n-1)\rho)\mathbb{I}_n - \frac{\rho}{(1-\rho)(1+(n-1)\rho)}\mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}'$$

for the inverse of $\mathbb{C}(\rho, n)$ when $-1/(n-1) \lt \rho \lt 1.$  For example, when $n=3$

$$\color{gray}{\Sigma(\rho, 3) = \frac{1}{(1-\rho)(1+2\rho)} \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \rho +1 & -\rho  & -\rho  \\
 -\rho  & \rho +1 & -\rho  \\
 -\rho  & -\rho  & \rho +1 \\
\end{array}
\right)}.$$

Let the vector of random variables $(X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n)$ have distribution function

$$f_{\rho, n}(\mathbf{x}) = \frac{\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{x}\Sigma(\rho, n)\mathbf{x}'\right)}{(2\pi)^{n/2}\left((1-\rho)^{n-1}(1+(n-1)\rho)\right)^{1/2}}$$

where $\mathbf{x} = (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$. For example, when $n=3$ this equals

$$\color{gray}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^{3}(1-\rho)^2(1+2\rho)}}
\exp\left(-\frac{(1+\rho)(x^2+y^2+z^2) - 2\rho(xy+yz+zx)}{2(1-\rho)(1+2\rho)}\right)}.$$

The correlation matrix for these $n$ random variables is $\mathbb{C}(\rho, n).$

[image: Figure]

*Contours of the density functions $f_{\rho,3}.$  From left to right, $\rho=-4/10, 0, 4/10, 8/10$.  Note how the density shifts from being concentrated near the plane $x+y+z=0$ to being concentrated near the line $x=y=z$.*

The special cases $\rho = -1/(n-1)$ and $\rho = 1$ can also be realized by *degenerate* distributions; I won't go into the details except to point out that in the former case the distribution can be considered supported on the hyperplane $\mathbf{x}.\mathbf{1}=0$, where it is a sum of identically distributed mean-$0$ Normal distribution, while in the latter case (perfect positive correlation) it is supported on the line generated by $\mathbf{1}'$, where it has a mean-$0$ Normal distribution.

---

#### More about non-degeneracy

A review of this analysis makes it clear that the correlation matrix $\mathbb{C}(-1/(n-1), n)$ has a rank of $n-1$ and $\mathbb{C}(1, n)$ has a rank of $1$ (because only one eigenvector has a nonzero eigenvalue).  For $n\ge 2$, this makes the correlation matrix degenerate in either case.  Otherwise, the existence of its inverse $\Sigma(\rho, n)$ proves it is nondegenerate.

Comment: This is a great answer

Answer (score 27):

Your correlation matrix is

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1&\rho&\rho\\ \rho&1&\rho\\ \rho&\rho&1 \end{pmatrix}$$

The matrix is positive semidefinite if the leading principal minors are all non-negative. The principal minors are the determinants of the "north-west" blocks of the matrix, i.e. 1, the determinant of

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1&\rho\\ \rho&1\end{pmatrix}$$

and the determinant of the correlation matrix itself.

1 is obviously positive, the second principal minor is $1-\rho^2$, which is nonnegative for any admissible correlation $\rho\in[-1,1]$. The determinant of the entire correlation matrix is

$$ 2\rho^3-3\rho^2+1.$$

The plot shows the determinant of the function over the range of admissible correlations $[-1,1]$.
[image]

You see the function is nonnegative over the range given by @stochazesthai (which you could also check by finding the roots of the determinantal equation).

Comment: Aren't we assuming in your answer that $Var( )=1$? Why can we?

Comment: @Anold You seem to be reading "covariance" where "correlation" is written.

Answer (score 7):

There exist random variables $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ with pairwise correlations $\rho_{XY} = \rho_{YZ} = \rho_{XZ} = \rho$ if and only if the correlation matrix is positive semidefinite. This happens only for $\rho \in [-\frac{1}{2},1]$.

Comment: can you explain this in very simple terms.

Comment: I don't think there exists an explanation that does not require the knowledge of matrix algebra. I suggest you to look at the Wikipedia page (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Negative-definite.2C_semidefinite_and_indefinite_matrices).

Comment: I found an explanation that requires only basic (high school level) algebra and have included that in my answer.