# A tricky question about correlation

Tags: correlation, mathematical-statistics, descriptive-statistics

$X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are three random variables where their pairwise correlations are the same, i.e., $corr(X,Y)=corr(Y,Z)=corr(X,Z)=\rho$ what are the possible values of $\rho$?  I was asked this in an interview (data analyst).

Comment: Duplicate of [Bound for the correlation of three random variables](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/72790/6633).