# Minimum covariance of 2 random variables given the covariance of each with a third random variable

Tags: correlation, covariance

If we have 3 random variables, with the first two with a covariance of 0.1 and the second two with a covariance of 0.1, what is the minimum covariance of the first and third? Is there a generalized solution on bounds on covariance matrices?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bound for the correlation of three random variables](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72790/bound-for-the-correlation-of-three-random-variables)

Comment: how does the solution in "Bound for the correlation of three random variables" help solve this problem?

Comment: @gung, While the two questions are closely related, I don't think this is a duplicate. In that question it was assumed that the correlation between any pair of the three was the same, and the "same correlation" assumption here is only between two of the three pairs. The OP would certainly benefit from reading the answers given to that question and may be able to answer this question after having studied them closely, but it still requires some non-trivial thought. (Incidentally I'm sure I've seen a question that's closer to this one, but can't remember where!)

Comment: @Silverfish, a more interesting problem is a case where you have n variables, and the covariance matrix is known except for cells representing covariance between first two variables. Then the problem is what are the bounds of values of this cell?

Answer (score 6):

What (I believe) you want to know is for which values of $x$ your covariance matrix remains positive semi-definite (see property two [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix#Properties)). I take your matrix to be a correlation matrix for simplicity, so that correlations are 1:
$$
V=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0.1&x\\
0.1&1&0.1\\
x&0.1&1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
By [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester's_criterion), we need to know if the determinants of all principal minors are nonnegative. Now, 1 and $1-0.1^2$ obviously are, independent of $x$.

For the determinant, I asked [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+det%7B%7B1%2C+.1%2C+x%7D%2C+%7B0.1%2C+1%2C+.1%7D%2C+%7Bx%2C.1%2C+1%7D%7D%3D0+for+x), which gave the figure below. So $x\in[-49/50,1]$.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

(The answer has been rewritten)

Provided that you mean exactly what you are asking (i. e. such information is given about the *covariances*, not the *correlations* between the random variables), the answer is as follows.

**Firstly, the covariance of the first and third random variable may not exist. Secondly, even if it does exist, there is no minimum covariance of the first and third random variable, it can be arbitrarily low**.

As an example of non-existence, consider random variables $\xi_{1}  \sim F(x): \rho(x) = |x|^{-3}, |x|>1, \xi_{3} = \xi_{1}$.
Since such distribution is symmetric with respect to zero, the expectations of these random variables are zero. Due to their dependence, $cov(\xi_{1}, \xi_{3}) = D(\xi_{1}) = \infty$. However, I can find a degree $b$ such that $\xi_{2}=\xi_{1}^{\frac{1}{b}}: cov(\xi_{2}, \xi_{1}) = cov(\xi_{2}, \xi_{3}) = 0.1$, and $E\xi_{2}=0$ as well.

To instantiate the possibility of an arbitrary covariance, consider a very special case: I have three samples of mentioned random variables, say $\{x\}_{i=1}^n, \{y\}_{i=1}^n, \{z\}_{i=1}^n,$ of identical size $n$, such that $\bar{x}, \bar{y}, \bar{z} = 0$. Than their sample covariances would be simply $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nx_{i}\cdot y_{i}, \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nz_{i}\cdot y_{i}, \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nx_{i}\cdot z_{i}$, which in an orthonormal basis are respectively identical to normed scalar products of respective vectors $x, y, z$ in an N-dimensional space: $\frac{1}{n}(x, y), \frac{1}{n}(y, z), \frac{1}{n}(x, z)$, which are in turn $\frac{1}{n}|x|\cdot|y|\cdot cos(x, y) ; \frac{1}{n}|y|\cdot |z|\cdot cos(y,z); \frac{1}{n}|x|\cdot |z|\cdot cos(x,z) $ in geometric interpretation.

Now let these vectors $x, y, z$ be all in a single 3-dimensional plane, and the angles between them would be $\pi/3, \pi/3$ and $2\cdot \pi/3$ respectively, then the cosines are $0.5, 0.5, -0.5$.

In a given example, the initial conditions for covariances are satisfied whenever $|x|\cdot |y|=0.2n$ and $|z|\cdot |y|=0.2n$, and we still have a freedom to set $|x|=|z|$ to arbitrary values, setting $|y| = \frac{0.2n}{|x|}$.

Now consider **a sequence of such vectors** $ \{\vec{x}\}_{j=1}^\infty$, say tuples with $\pm h$ inside of dimension $j$, ($(h), (h,-h), \dots )$, then for every $j$: $|\vec{x}_{j}| = |\vec{z}_{j}|=h\cdot \sqrt{j} $ and then $cov(\vec{x_j}, \vec{z_j})=-\frac{j\cdot h}{2j}$. The last figure apparently converges to $-\frac{h}{2}$ (where $h$ is arbitrary) while the two other covariances remain stable at $0.1$. One could argue that such $x$ sample does not look like random, but here the underlying distribution is not discussed at all and in a sample case of $x_{i} \sim \{h, p = \frac{1}{2}, -h\; else\}$ the length of $\vec{x}$ would be exactly the same.

The entire considerations have been made about empirical covariances, but as long as the size of a sample goes to infinity, the [Continuous mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem) ensures that if a theoretical covariance between the first and third variable exists, the empirical one should converge to it in probability. The example shown before shows that the theoretical $cov(x, z)$ may not even exist. By configuring another $h$ sequence, one could make the covariance converge to arbitrarily low finite numbers.

There can also be a more concise and intuitive explanation.
As covariances are expressed in squared units of measurement, one can simply adjust the units of $x$ and $z$, compensating these shifts with scaling $y$ conversely, and thus scale the covariance $cov(x,z)$ arbitrarily, so the "generalized solution" here is that in such problem setup there are actually **no bounds on distinct elements of covariance matrices** (in both sides).
Nevertheless, any covariance matrix should still satisfy its basic requirement: it is always a squared symmetrical positive-semidefinite matrix.

The answer above suggests a great approach but it seems to have simply changed the *'covariances'* to *'correlations'* which cannot be simply done since it would require scaling the covariance matrix elements differently. Posing the analogous answer about correlations leads to completely different conclusions.

Comment: For this reply to be complete, it would help to relate its discussion of *correlations* with the subject of the question, which concerns *covariances.*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The reasoning looks good, but statements like "there are .. no bounds on covariance matrices" could all too easily be misunderstood as meaning "any matrix could be a covariance matrix."  Even when that is qualified as a "square symmetric matrix" it would be incorrect.

Comment: @whuber I fixed the statement about matrices, and a glitch in a general example, and, moreover, I still do not really know how to show a simple example that pulls covariance to *minus infinity*, not just any infinity. With the way I contrapted the generic example, I cannot make it infinitely low without exploding the numbers in vectors and thus demolishing the theoretical expectations for x and z, which are a requirement for existent pairwise covariances.   Many thanks for patrolling the question. Anyway, it looks like resolved now.