Product of correlations properties
Is corr(A,B)*corr(B,C) somewhat related to corr(A,C), or completely independent?
Are there any properties of this product (corr(A,B)*corr(B,C))?

Please search our site for the answers.  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/254282 looks particularly relevant.  So does https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/168485.

On the contrary, you have a single constraint on a $3\times 3$ correlation matrix.  That is so closely related to the well-known constraints of positive definiteness (explained in the links) that little else needs to be said.

From the earlier question If A and B are correlated with C, why are A and B not necessarily correlated?, if the three correlations are $\rho,\sigma ,\tau$,  then you have  $$1 + 2 \rho \sigma \tau - \left(\rho^2 + \sigma^2 + \tau^2\right) \ge 0.$$  This does not transform into some simple relationship between $\rho\sigma$ and $\tau$, though you can say $$\rho\sigma-\sqrt{(\rho\sigma)^2+1-\rho^2-\sigma^2} \le \tau \le \rho\sigma+\sqrt{(\rho\sigma)^2+1-\rho^2-\sigma^2}.$$
Since $\rho \in [-1,1]$ and $\sigma \in [-1,1]$, this interval for $\tau$ will be a subset of $[-1,1]$.

Interestingly this doesn't seem to be the same as the formula provided here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/254282/completing-a-3-times-3-correlation-matrix-2-coefficients-of-the-3-given

@Caterina In what way are they not the same? If $\rho=0.6$ and $\sigma=0.8$ then $\rho\sigma-\sqrt{(\rho\sigma)^2+1-\rho^2-\sigma^2}=0$ and $\rho\sigma+\sqrt{(\rho\sigma)^2+1-\rho^2-\sigma^2}=0.96$, so $0 \le \tau\le 0.96$, which is what the answers in your linked question say.

You're right I was looking at a slightly different formula $\rho\sigma \pm \sqrt{1-\rho^2}\sqrt{1-\sigma^2}$, but they turn out to be the same after simplifying, my mistake.

Short answer
You ask whether in a system of three variables, the product of two correlations is independent of the third correlation. More generally, it can be answered that the third correlation depends on the values of the other correlations. The reason for this is related to correlation matrices and positive-definiteness, which might not be immediately evident and hence why one could think the related questions proposed by whuber are not relevant. Let's first see some intuition:
Intuition
Let us recall that the correlation can be seen as a function of the angle between two lines$^*$. Our question then becomes: if we have three lines and I fix the angle between two pairs of them, is the third angle constrained in any way? I invite you to try this with pens or fingers and note that the locations that the third line can take are inscribed within a specific cone which respects the fixed angles.
Long answer
A system of three variables and their correlations necessarily involves some constraints due to the constraints of their correlation matrix, namely, its positive-definiteness, which is in turn related to the determinant of the matrix. In practice, this implies that the possible correlations between these three variables cannot take any value between $-1$ and $+1$, but rather a smaller set of these. Visually speaking, this means that the possible values in the entries of a three-dimensional correlation matrix do not span a three-dimensional cube, but rather a smaller volume within it. From Figure 1 in Rousseeuw and Molenberghs (1994), you can see that this specific shape is kind of an inflated tetrahedron:

Further, you see that its slices are ellipses. This means that for two given correlation values the third correlation value ought to be within the constraints of this ellipse. This ellipse is precisely defined due to positive-definiteness constraints:
$$
\operatorname{Cor}(A, B)^2 + \operatorname{Cor}(B, C)^2 -  2 \operatorname{Cor}(A, C) \operatorname{Cor}(A, B) \operatorname{Cor}(B, C) = 1 - \operatorname{Cor}(A, C)^2
$$
It might not be clear that this equation defines an ellipse, but then you might need to check the relationship between the canonical and quadratic forms of a conic section.
So, answering your question, the product of the two correlations is related to the third correlation on behalf of the restrictions the two correlations impose on the possible values of the third correlation.

$^*$: More precisely, as the cosine similarity between two centered vectors.
References
Rousseeuw, P. J., & Molenberghs, G. (1994). The shape of correlation matrices. The American Statistician, 48(4), 276-279.
