# Set of uncorrelated but linearly dependent variables

Tags: correlation, mathematical-statistics, multicollinearity

Is it possible to have a set of $K$ variables  that are uncorrelated but linearly dependent?

i.e.
$cor(x_i, x_j)=0$ and $ \sum_{i=1}^K a_ix_i=0$

If yes can you write an example ?

EDIT:
From the answers it follows that it is not possible.

Would it at least be possible that $\mathbb{P}(|\hat \rho_{x_i, x_j}-\hat \rho_{x_i, v}|<\epsilon)$ where $\hat\rho$ is the estimated correlation coefficient estimated from $n$ samples of the variables and $v$ is a variable that is uncorrelated with $x_i$.

I am thinking something like $x_K=\dfrac{1}{K} \sum_{i=1}^{K-1} x_i$  $K>>0$

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As @RUser4512's answer shows, uncorrelated random variables cannot be linearly dependent. But, *nearly* uncorrelated random variables *can* be linearly dependent, and one example of these is something dear to the
statistician's heart.

Suppose that $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^K$ is a
set of $K$ uncorrelated unit-variance random variables with common mean $\mu$. 
Define
$Y_i = X_i - \bar{X}$ where $\bar{X} = \frac 1K \sum_{i=1}^K X_i$.
Then, the $Y_i$ are zero-mean random variables such that 
$\sum_{i=1}^K Y_i = 0$, that is, they are linearly dependent.
Now, $$Y_i = \frac{K-1}{K} X_i - \frac 1K\sum_{j \neq i}X_j$$
so that 
$$\operatorname{var}(Y_i) = \left(\frac{K-1}{K}\right)^2+\frac{K-1}{K^2}
= \frac{K-1}{K}$$
while
$$\operatorname{cov}(Y_i,Y_j) = -2\left(\frac{K-1}{K}\right)\frac 1K
+ \frac{K-2}{K^2}= \frac{-1}{K}$$
showing that the $Y_i$ are *nearly* uncorrelated random variables
with correlation coefficient $\displaystyle -\frac{1}{K-1}$.

See also [this earlier answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/72795/6633)
of mine.

Comment: This is a really nice example!

Answer (score 9):

No.

Suppose one of the $a_i$ is non zero. Without loss of generality, let's assume $a_1=1$.

For $K=2$, this implies $x_1=-a_2x_2$ and $cor(x_1,x_2)=-1$. But this correlation is zero. $a_1$ must be zero as well, contradicting the existence of a linear relationship.

For any $K$, $x_1=-\sum_{i>1}a_ix_i$ and $cor(x_1,x_k)=-1$. But, by you hypothesis, $cor(x_1,x_k)=0$. The $a_i$'s are zero (for $i>1$) and so must be $a_1$.

Comment: In the case of gaussian vectors, you even have a one-line proof (that I prefer to keep as a comment). Correlation equals 0 implies independence. $\sum_i a_ix_i =0$ implies $\sum_i a_i^2 =0$ and you are done.

Comment: Very good answer. It would be nice if you can answer also to the edited question.

Comment: The edited question is much harder ;) I assume that $v$ and $x_K$ refer the the same thing ? I don't see the point of the 1/K factor, if you are looking for a correlation, it will not change anything to the final result

Comment: 1/K was required to make $cor(x_K, x_i)=1/K$ .

Answer (score 4):

This may be cheating a bit, but if we define ‘uncorrelated’ as having a *covariance* of 0, the answer is *yes*. Let $X$ and $Y$ both be zero with probability 1. Then

$\mathop{\mathrm{Cov}}(X,Y)=
\mathop{\mathrm{E}}(XY)-\mathop{\mathrm{E}}(X)\mathop{\mathrm{E}}(Y)=0-0=0$

while $X+Y=0$, so $X$ and $Y$ are linearly dependent (by your definition).

Though if you require that the *correlation* is defined, i.e. that the variances of both $X$ and $Y$ are strictly positive, it’s *not* possible to find variables fulfilling your criteria (see the other answers).