# How to compute the variance for this process?

Tags: correlation, variance, mean, autocorrelation

I have a sequences of random *iid* *non-correlated* positive integers sampled from some (unknown) distribution $\boldsymbol X=[n_1,n_2,...,n_N]$.

From it, I built another sequence in the following way:

$$ [1,2,3,...,n_1, 1,2,3,...,n_2, ...,1,2,3,...,n_N]$$

That is, I replaced each $n_i$ with a list $1,2,3,..,n_i$ (note: the lowest allowed value for $n_i$ is 1).

**Q:** How to get the variance of the mean of the last list? If it be possible, I would prefer a solution in terms of the $n_i$s.

For the first list I just used $\operatorname{Var}(\bar X)=\frac{\operatorname{Var}(X_i)}{N}$. I tried to solve the problem following [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/588789/meaning-of-average-correlation-in-var-bar-x) approach. But I do not get good results (sometimes I get a negative result).

Comment: The number of values in the new sequence is

$$\nu = \sum_{i=1}^N n_i.$$ 

Their sum is 

$$S = \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{(n_i+1)n_i}{2}.$$

By definition, the mean is 

$$m = \frac{S}{\nu} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^N (n_i+1)n_i}{2\sum_{i=1}^N n_i} = \frac{1}{2} +  \frac{1}{2}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N n_i^2}{\sum_{i=1}^N n_i}.$$

This does not simplify.  *That's as far as you can go in this general setting.* If you would like to specify the distribution of the $n_i,$ we could give more specific results.

Comment: @whuber Thank you. I do not know the underlying distribution. Values arise from a chemical process. I was thinking if it would be possible to decompose it as some kind of sums of variances. That is, dividing the sequence in blocks for each $n_i$: 1,2,3,...,$n_i$. The variance of each sequence would be $(n_i+1)(2n_i+1)/6-(n_i+1)^2/4$ if I am not wrong (it gives me the same result that the common expression for the variance of a set of numbers).
I am not looking for an unique result. I look for some way to compute it for each experiment. Do you think that there could be some chance for it?

Comment: @whuber I had in mind that as the $n_i$ are uncorrelated maybe knowing the variances of each sublist would lead me to the variance of the entire list. Does it makes sense?

Comment: Each term in the sum for $m$ involves *all* the $N$ random variables in its denominator. This creates a strong interdependency, as well as creating algebraic difficulties in the evaluation of variances even when you do stipulate the common distribution of the $n_i.$  (Your formula neglects that dependency and therefore is incorrect, although it might sometimes be an OK approximation.) Out of curiosity, what aspect of a chemical process can be modeled in this way? The use of integral random variables is unusual.  Possibly a more tractable model can be found.

Comment: @whuber I understand. The formula is just for the variance of a increasing sequence, but of course, it is just part of the numerator. Regarding your question: it is associated with the duration of adsorbates on a surface. I think that in statistical terms what I want to do is to compute de variance of the mean residual time.

Comment: It is likely that an integral random variable is not a good model for a duration.

Comment: Thanks @whuber It seems to me that my problem was already solved in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.02484.pdf (last one line eq. from page 2)  but unfortunately it is expressed in mathematical terms that are inaccessible to me.

Comment: The notation in that paper obscures the basic simplicity of the equations.  But I cannot see any connection between it and the situation you describe here.  Why not ask us about the problem you really have, rather than about a model of it that might or might not be useful or tractable?