# Find the values of $ a$ so that A is positive definite (p.d)

Tags: self-study, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, mathematical-statistics

Let $A=(1-a)I_n + a J_n$
Find the values of $~a~$ so the Matrix is p.d ?
Note:$~I_n~$ is the identity matrix and $~J_n$ is the $1's$ matrix.

I know that $~~A$ is p.d $~iff~λ_i >0$ so, I need to choose $a$ so that $~λ_i >0$

First I tried to use the definition to find the eigen $det(A-λI_n)=0$
but it real complicated.

any help would be appreciated.

This question from  **A First Course in Linear Model Theory** by  Nalini, chapter 2.

Update: Trying to use the hint by @ whuber

By using the idea of inspection, I found  the Gershgorin theorem ( first time I heard about it)
https://math.la.asu.edu/~gardner/Gcircle.pdf

By the theorem we conclude that all$~ λi~$ in the disk

$D(1, (n-1)a)~~center~ at~ 1~, ~~and~ radius~ (n-1)a$

so in order to have positive value for $~ λi~$ we need to take

$|(n-1)a|<1~~$ hence, $-1/n-1<a<1/n-1$

@ whuber Is there another  idea without using this theorem because we did not cover it in my class? Thanks

Comment: Hint: because $I_n$ and $J_n$ commute, they have the same eigenspaces.  This enables you to know the eigenspaces by inspection and allows you to read off the eigenvalues immediately.

Comment: Please add the self-study tag and have a look at its [wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info)

Comment: Since $A-\lambda I_n=(1-a-\lambda)I_n+a\mathbf1_n\mathbf1_n^\top$, determinant of $A-\lambda I$ can be easily calculated if you want using [Matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma). It is important to note that $A$ is symmetric, for only then we can say that $A$ is p.d. iff its eigenvalues are positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Let's start with a definition and see how far it can take us.**  $A$ is *positive definite* if and only if for every nonzero vector $x,$ $x^\prime A x \gt 0.$  Let us therefore lead off with this latter expression and use what we know about $A.$

To avoid interrupting the flow of algebra, let me observe right now that $J_n$ is an outer product:

$$J_n = \mathbf{1}_n \mathbf{1}_n^\prime$$

where $\mathbf{1}_n = (1,1,\ldots,1)^\prime$ is a column vector of ones.  Note, too, that

$$x^\prime \mathbf{1}_n = \left(x^\prime \mathbf{1}_n\right)^\prime =\mathbf{1}_n^\prime x$$

because both sides are scalars.

So:

$$\eqalign{
x^\prime A x &= x^\prime\left((1-a)I_n + a J_n\right) x \\
&= (1-a) x^\prime I_n x + a x^\prime \left(\mathbf{1}_n \mathbf{1}_n^\prime\right) x \\
&= (1-a)\|x\|^2 + a \left(x^\prime \mathbf{1}_n\right) \left(\mathbf{1}_n^\prime x\right) \\
&= (1-a)\|x\|^2 + a\left(\mathbf{1}_n^\prime x\right)^2.
}$$

At this point there are many ways to proceed: exploit well-known inequalities; use Lagrange multipliers; apply induction; change to a suitable basis; *etc*.  I leave the choice to you and your mathematical taste.  If you're still not sure of the answer, read over the replies at [Bound for the correlation of three random variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72790) to see what it looks like for $n=3$ and generalize.

---

**Perhaps the easiest and most insightful route to a solution is a geometric one.**  The geometry is brought out by generalizing the relation $J_n=\mathbf{1}_n\mathbf{1}_n^\prime$ to

$$J = \mathbf{u}\mathbf{u}^\prime$$

for some arbitrary nonzero vector $\mathbf u.$  This vector defines a subspace of dimension $n-1$ *via*

$$\mathbf{u}^\perp = \{\mathbf x \in\mathbb{R}^n\mid \mathbf{u}^\prime \mathbf x = 0\}.$$

This is the kernel of $J:$ that is, $J$ restricted to $\mathbf{u}^\perp$ is the zero transformation.

When $(\mathbf u_2, \mathbf u_3,\ldots, \mathbf u_n)$ is a basis of $\mathbf{u}^\perp,$ adjoining $\mathbf u_1 = \mathbf u$ gives a basis $\mathcal U = (\mathbf u_1, \mathbf u_2, \ldots, \mathbf u_n)$ for the entire space.  Because obviously

$$I_n \mathbf{u}_j = \mathbf{u}_j$$

for all $j=1,2,\ldots, n$ and

$$J \mathbf{u}_1 = J \mathbf{u} = \left(\mathbf{u}\mathbf{u}^\prime\right)\mathbf u = \mathbf{u}\left(\mathbf{u}^\prime \mathbf u\right) = ||\mathbf u||^2 \mathbf{u},$$

*$\mathcal U$ is an eigenbasis for **both** $I_n$ and $J.$*  Consequently it is an eigenbasis for any linear combination like $(1-a)I_n + aJ,$ *all* of whose eigenvalues can be read directly from the coefficients on the right hand sides of the equations

$$((1-a)I_n + aJ)\mathbf{u}_1 = \left((1-a) + a||\mathbf{u}||^2\right)\mathbf{u}_1$$

and

$$((1-a)I_n + aJ)\mathbf{u}_j = (1-a)\mathbf{u}_j$$

for $j=2, 3, \ldots, n.$  Since this linear combination is positive semidefinite if and only if all eigenvalues are nonnegative, we have discovered the necessary and sufficient conditions

$$ (1 - a) + a||\mathbf{u}||^2 \ge 0;\ (1-a) \ge 0.$$

Solving for $a$ in the case $||\mathbf u||^2 \gt 1$ gives

> $$ \frac{-1}{||\mathbf u||^2 - 1} \le a \le 1.$$

When $||\mathbf u||^2 \le 1,$ there is no lower bound on $a:$ only the upper bound holds.

For the case $J = J_n$ in the question, $\mathbf u = (1,1,\ldots, 1)$ for which $||\mathbf u||^2 = n.$