# Distribution of correlation of A-B given correlation of A-C and B-C

Tags: correlation

Suppose the correlation between vectors $A$ and $C$ of size $N$ is some value $r_{AC}$, and likewise for $B$, $C$, and $r_{BC}$. What is the distribution for $r_{AB}$?

Because correlations are cosines of angles between unit vectors, it is easy enough to compute the minimum and maximum potential values for $r_{AB}$. I have an intuition that this can be extended by calculating (analytically) the distribution of angles from some vector to some hypersphere, but I don't know how to start.

Comment: Have you seen [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/72790/6633) and its answers?

Comment: I had not, but they only appear to indicate the bounds, not the distribution, as far as I understand the answers.

Comment: Unless you specify some distributions for $A,B,C$, your question regarding the _distribution_ is meaningless; $r_{AB}$ is a _constant_ that satisfies bounds given in the answers to the question cited.  Also, _read_ the [answer by whuber](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/72798/6633) more carefully, especially the section titled "Proof of Sufficiency of Conditions" where he assumes that the vector components are iid standard normal random variables.