# exchangable variance covariance matrix

Tags: correlation, covariance-matrix, generalized-estimating-equations, geepack

I was trying to learn how to estimate exchangable correlation matrix. I asked ChatGPT to give me an example so that I can learn the steps and ChatGPT gave me this example

```
Lines <- "ID    Time   Z
 1     1     -1.5
 1     2     -1.5
 1     3      0.5
 1     4      0.5
 2     1     -0.5
 2     2     -0.5
 2     3      1.5
 2     4      1.5"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)

resd   <-    DF$Z
n      <-    length(resd)
sigma  <-    var(resd)
rho    <-    1 / (n - 1) * sum(resd[-1] * resd[-n]) / sigma
ExCorr <-    matrix(rho, 4, 4)
diag(ExCorr) <- 1

   1      0.325    0.325    0.325     
   0.325  1        0.325    0.325
   0.325  0.325    1        0.325
   0.325  0.325    0.325    1
```

I like to get references for this method of estimating the exchangeable correlation matrix
`1 / (n - 1) * sum(resd[-1] * resd[-n]) / sigma`, how do I identify the source for this formula ? Thanks.

Comment: You already identified the source: ChatGPT.  Exchangeability implies all correlation coefficients between distinct variables are the same.  This is so evident that you shouldn't feel obliged to cite any sources for support.  There is a subtlety: those common correlation coefficients are restricted to the interval $[-1/(n-1), 1]$ for $n$ variables.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/72798/919 for an explanation and illustration.  The specific formula used by ChatGPT, though, is incorrect.  It's actually a formula for the lag-1 *autocorrelation* coefficient of a time series.

Comment: @whuber, Thanks, somehow the estimates from this approach lag-1 autocorrelation coefficient appears as the alpha from geeglm , `geefit$geese$alpha` when I set corstr = "exchangeable". I will go through your references. Thanks