Eigenvalues of 4x4 hollow matrix

I'm tackling this practice question, and I doubt it's a plug and chug problem. The matrix is symmetric, and it also looks like it may be related to upper-lower, triangular? Wikipedia calls it a hollow matrix and Wolfram alpha gave a weird answer and none of the steps. I get stuck on the determinant step of finding eigenvalues where the 4x4 matrix looks too big to compute the determinant efficiently.
Any ideas on how to move forward with this?

Maybe there is a trick to it, but it is certainly possible (maybe not fun) to get the determinant via cofactor expansion or by reducing to triangular, get the characteristic equation, and then solve using rational root theorem and division.

Use $A = \mathbf 1 \mathbf 1^\prime - \mathbb{I},$ which expresses it as a rank-one perturbation of the (negative) identity matrix.  The rest is (almost) trivial, especially if you just make some good guesses and check them.  You can find this kind of calculation carried out explicitly for an essentially similar exercise in the section "Derivation of the conditions on $\rho$" at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/72798/919.  cc @wzbillings
