# Range of correlation between two stacked pairs of data

Tags: correlation, descriptive-statistics

[Similar](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4444825/range-of-correlation) [questions](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/06/17/covariance-and-law-of-cosines/) have been [asked](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5747/if-a-and-b-are-correlated-with-c-why-are-a-and-b-not-necessarily-correlated/5753#5753) before where we have Cor(X,Y) and Cor(X,Z) and we want to find out the range of correlations of a linear combination of X & Z with Y. Or a third correlation: (X,Z).

However I'm lost at a different formulation of the problem. Let's say you have two pairs of random variables: ($X_1$, $Y_1$), and ($X_2$, $Y_2$), both pairs have the same number of data points, and correlations of $\rho_1 = 0.8$ and $\rho_2 = 0.5$, respectively.

---

Now let's say you "stacked" $X_1$ and $X_2$ on top of each other, and did the same for $Y_1$ and $Y_2$. We call this new stacked pair: $X_3$, $Y_3$

How do you get the *range* of $\rho_3$ in terms of $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$?

This seems different than just doing $Cor(X_1+X_2, Y_1+Y_2)$ right? I have no clue where to even begin here...

It's easy to solve this question if it's $Cor(X_1+X_2, Y_1+Y_2)$, but for some reason I am completely lost when the datasets are stacked....

Comment: **Draw a picture.** The range goes from $-1$ to $1$ and cannot generally be reduced.  It's easy to see: just shift the means of the $X_i$ and $Y_i$ around.  In some configurations one point cloud is far above and to the right of the other, giving a correlation arbitrarily close to $1;$ and in other configurations one cloud is far below and to the right of the other, with a correlation arbitrarily close to $-1.$